# MomentJS - Not giving the correct output consistently

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So, having issue with moment. sometimes. gives great month sometimes gives inaccurate info.

[Fiddle for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36ffe8mt/)

JS Fiddle includes the following Code

```
var t = '01/06/2018';
var m = moment(t);
alert(m.month());
```

So you can see here that moment returns back the month is 0 but really the month is 1. ?

Why is moment doing this?

What can I do to prevent this?

Edited:

So I am working with bootstrap-datepicker .

Display wise I would like it to display like MM/DD/YYYY

The bootstrap-datepicker uses moments.

I did something like this

```
$('.dpick').datetimepicker({format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'});
```

So that way it shows up accordingly. I can access the moment object like this.

```
$($(this).closest('tr').find('input.dpick')[0]).data("DateTimePicker").date()
```

Which gives me back a moment object.

But I need to send it to my API like this
YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Your date is being parsed as `MM/DD/YYYY`, `month()` is zero based , so you would like to add 1 to your month.

Comment: You should store in an unambiguous `yyyy/mm/dd` format and only display it in the ambiguous format if required by the current locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `format("M")` to get the month number in moment like this:

```js
var t = '01/06/2018';
var m = moment(t);
alert(m.format("M"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I am working with date picker. 
Display wise I would like it to display like MM/DD/YYYY

So in my datepicker. It uses moment.
I did something like this
$('.dpick').datetimepicker({format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'});

So that way it shows up accordingly. I can access the moment object like this.

$($(this).closest('tr').find('input.dpick')[0]).data("DateTimePicker").date()

Which gives me back a moment object.

But I need to send it to my API like this
YYYY-MM-DD

I edited the description to have more understanding

Comment: Without much coffee. I did not read your code carefully enough. Thank you. 

I simply used the format command to output the current moment value in the way I wish.

Comment: Ankit, maybe you can enlighten me. I am adding date picker dynamically. to the objects after writing to DB. But the datepicker dropdown shows completely at the top of the table. I will create a new Stack question. and link here.

Comment: Sure @GrafixMasta. It will be easy and appropriate if you create a new question for this.

Comment: Pfft, I can only post once every 90 minutes. haha. OOPS. hahah

Comment: So I just added quite a few notes. and I noticed all the date and time picker drop downs are appearing randomly. From my knowledge based upon the first instance. Once my 90 mins is up I will post. But you would think the click event would establish the target for the datetimepicker to offeset itself.

Comment: Sorry @GrafixMasta i am not getting you, what you want to achieve here and what you have achieved so far.

Comment: No prob, here is the link to the new question
[New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595499/bootstrap-datetimepicker-dynamically-add-shows-up-in-wrong-area)